# Means of different call label formats in IDA

Tags: disassembly, ida, assembly

What is of different label formats of `call` instruction means in IDA?
Like:

```
call  Cla$ENABEL
call  ds:Cla$PushString
call  ds:GETNAME@Folosososososos
```

Thanks